# How to catch a stack trace from jvm.dll?

Tags: java, windows, visual-c++, dll, stdout

I've got a C++ console application that uses a third-party dll (jvm.dll, indirectly) that uses printf to print various error messages (Java stacktrace). I need to catch these stacktraces to a string in order to process them further, or at least to see them printed on the console.

The thing is that I see the stacktrace only when debugging my application in VisualStudio (VS 2010). When I run my application in the "normal way", i.e. from the command line, nothing is printed on the console. So VS is able to somehow interfere the java output and display it. I need to be able to do the same thing.

I've already tried freopen(), but without success. Also, I've found [this question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vclanguage/thread/729db35a-1508-48c9-a9f5-5724b515068b) on the same problem, but without a clear answer.

Comment: VS probably just redirects stdout to its own destination.

Comment: Well, but HOW does VS do it? I wasn't successful in that. 
Note that printf from the dll must go elsewhere than printf from the application, because the latter is visible on the console while the former is not.

Comment: is there any way you can run it in another shell and grab its `stdout` that way?

Comment: How do you know that jvm.dll uses printf?

Comment: jvm.dll uses the Java equivalent of printf, i.e. System.out.println().

To be more precise, a common way of handling an error in Java is:

try {
  ....
} catch (SomeException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}

As the dll prints the stacktrace, it is safe to expect that it uses this construct.

Comment: Unfortunately not. Jvm.dll is used from my application indirectly. To be precise, my testing application uses a 3rd party dll that implements the JMS communication, and this dll internally uses Java. When I execute my whole application from the shell, it prints no stacktrace, so the redirected stdout wouldn't contain more. But my ultimate environment for the dlls is not my testing application, but another application which is not under my control. (And the stacktrace is not printed there as well.)

Comment: @Xarx: since the jvm.dll only prints the stacktrace when run from the debugger, I think it is safe to assume that it is *not* using that construct.  Perhaps it is using OutputDebugString.

Comment: It might help if you could tell us in general terms what sort of error condition triggers this behaviour.

Comment: The whole story is like this: I use the JMSC library from an application to allow communication using JMS. When an error occurs, like if the JMS queue is not find in the JNDI register, the JMSC library reports just "undetermined Java exception". If I need more details about the error, I need to use JMSC library with the same settings from my testing application in VS debugger. There I see the Java stacktrace printed on the console. However, when I run the same testing application from the shell, the stacktrace is not printed.